# How to pass props in vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Hi guys i been trying to pass props in vue routes so far i was able to achieve this below, but is not what i wanted.

**So far this works**

route.js

```
{
    path: '/register/',
    name: 'register',
    component: require('./views/Login').default,
}
```

home.vue

```
<router-link tag="li" :to="{ name: 'register', params: { isRegisteringMe: 'true' }}" class="btn btn-green m-top-20 menu-btn" v-show="!isLoggedIn">Register</router-link>
```

And in register.vue i can `console.log(this.$route.params.isRegisteringMe);` which will return `true` when i click on Register link.

This is fine but what happen is user wants to type in the url directly `website.com/register` this method will not work. So i try several method but still not getting no where when i write this below.

```
{
    path: '/register/:id',
    name: 'register',
    props: { isRegisteringMe: 'hi props'},
    component: require('./views/Login').default,
}
```

Or

```
{
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    props: { isRegisteringMe: 'hi'},
    params: { isRegisteringMe: 'hi'},
    component: require('./views/Login').default,
}
```

Trust me i tried many different combination but i am still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some misconception about the usage of params in vue-router. Params should be part of the path.

for e.g., if the path setting is like

```
{
    path: '/register/:id',
    // ...
}
```

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'register', params: { id: 'abc123', isRegisteringMe:'true' }}">Register</router-link>` will link the user to `register/abc123`.

since the path setting is `path: '/register/:id',`, `isRegisteringMe` param is not defined and won't be displayed in the url.

Params should be part of the path. I see a few way you can change this.

1. use url query for `isRegisteringMe`. for eg, `/register?isRegisteringMe=true` ( `<router-link :to="{ name: 'register', query: { isRegisteringMe: 'true' }}"`). and get the value from `$route.query.isRegisteringMe`

update:

if you want user to always have `isRegisteringMe:true` by default 
do a redirection in register component's `mounted`  lifecycle event.

2. set `isRegisteringMe` in the app's state, or preferably in vuex if you are using it. then in register component, get the state and use it accordingly.

hope that this move you towards the right direction.

Comment: I do understand that, but your solution is still using <router-link> to go to that route, which i know to get it working. But my question is if user didnt click on <router-link> but write it in the address bar, those params doesnt not get pass!

Comment: added some update. the point is that `isRegisteringMe` gotta be a part of the url for you to be able to control it