# id passed through params get lost on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, parameters

I have a component called `Subscribers` that receives props via params from another component called `Details`. I use the props received to make an API call to get the list of subscribers. This works well.

But an issue arises when the page is refreshed. The id that is passed via params is lost - becomes null. Cause of that `subscribers` which is defined as an empty array in data becomes undefined as seen in this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

This is how I am passing the params from `Details` component

```
<router-link class="unsubscribe" :to="{ name: 'fund-subscribers', params: {fundProp: fund, id: fund.id } }">View all subscribers to this fund</router-link>
```

Then I have this:

```
props: {
  fundProp: {
    type: Object,
    default() {
      return {
        id: null,
        title: '',
        description: ''
      };
    }
  },
},
data() {
  return {
    fund: this.fundProp,
    subscribers: [],
  }
},
```

Here is the route configuration code for `fund-subscribers`

```
{
  path: 'funds/:id/subscribers',
  name: 'fund-subscribers',
  component: Subscribers,
  meta: {
    title: 'Admin'
  },
  props: true
},
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes it does. But on the API call it is shown as `null`

Comment: @KirkLarkin done!

Comment: I think it is with the `id`. `fundProp` seems to be working fine, I started passing the `id` when I figured out that I'll need it for dynamic routing.

Comment: @KirkLarkin do you use VSCode? We could try VSCode live share, that will be better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940759/how-to-pass-props-in-vue-router
`fundProp` is not part of the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a way to resolve it. First, there was no need to pass `fundProp`, I could pass only the `id` via params to `router-link`

```
<router-link class="unsubscribe" :to="{ name: 'fund-subscribers', params: { id: fund.id } }">
  View all subscribers to this fund
</router-link>
```

With that done I can now make use of `this.$route.params.id`. Which I can set my fund to in my component's data, and then use it to make the API call.

```
data() {
  return {
    fund: this.$route.params.id
  }
},
```

The function that makes the request to server can use this path:
`/funds/${fund}/users`, instead of `/funds/${fund.id}/users`

I hope this helps someone later (and me too in the future).

To understand it better make use of the links below:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/route-params-not-showing-after-full-page-refresh/30364

https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html